# Hibernate version 3.2.6; Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property:

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

My code

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

public List<RemboursementElement> validerRemboursement(String numDossier) {
    //List<RemboursementElement> l= getHibernateTemplate().find("from entite.RemboursementElement r where r.NUMERO_DOSSIER_REM='"+numDossier+"'" );
    //return l;
    List<RemboursementElement> results = Lists.newArrayList();
    Session session=null;
    try {    StringBuilder hql = new StringBuilder();   
             hql.append("select ");
             hql.append(" tableRemboursement.NUMERO_DOSSIER_REM, "); 
             hql.append("tableRemboursement.MONTANT_REMBOURSE, "); 
             hql.append("tableRemboursement.ETAT_REMBOURSEMENT, ") ; 
             hql.append("tableRemboursement.MOTIF_REMBOURSEMENT  " );
             hql.append("from ");
             hql.append(RemboursementElement.class.getCanonicalName());
             hql.append("  as tableRemboursement ");
             hql.append(" where 1=1 and tableRemboursement.NUMERO_DOSSIER_REM =");
             hql.append("'"+numDossier+"'");
             hql.append("");

           //  Query query = getSession().createQuery(hql.toString());
              session=this.getSession();
              Query query = session.createQuery(hql.toString());
             query.setParameter("numDossier", numDossier);
             query.executeUpdate();

            List<RemboursementElement>  l= query.list();

            if(l.size()>0 && l.isEmpty()==false && l!=null) {
                if(l.iterator().hasNext()==true) {
                    results.addAll(l);
                }
            }else {
                System.out.println("liste vide !");
            }

            return results;

    } catch (QueryException e) {
       throw new HibernateQueryException(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The query formed by you is a mix of 2 things.
Your are setting parameter in query formattion and later on you are using setParameter function also which is throwing exception

In your code replace `hq.append("'"+numDossier+"'")`  with `hq.append(":numDossier")`